# Spring Data - Callable statement being closed while reading bytes from a Blob

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, mssql-jdbc

**Background**

I have a Spring Boot 3.0 application that uses Spring Data JPA to call a stored procedure. Here's the Spring Data repository that calls the stored procedure:

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, Long> {
    
    @Procedure(value="pValuation", outputParameterName="reportData")
    Blob getReportData(String carTypes, LocalDate tradeDate);
```

The stored procedure is within a SQL Server 2016 database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pValuation]
    @carTypes nvarchar(max),
    @tradeDate datetime,
    @reportData varbinary(max) out
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC RDO.pValuation
        @reportData = @reportData out,
        @CarTypes = @carTypes ,
        @Date = @tradeDate,
        @IncludeBaseData = true
END
```

I use a `Blob` instead of a `byte[]` for the out parameter of `varbinary(max)` because

1. The MS SQL JDBC driver (version mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17) returns a max of 8000 bytes when `byte[]` is used and
2. My stored procedure returns > 8000 bytes

I need to convert the `Blob` into a byte array for additional processing:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CarService {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    public Set<CarDto> getValuations(LocalDate date) {
        
        Blob reportData = carRepository.getReportData("sedan,truck", date);
        log.debug("got Blob");
        try {
            byte[] b= reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length());
            log.debug("exception thrown from line above... will never log this");
            return carRepository.getCarValuations(b);
        } 
        catch (SQLException convertBlobToBytesException) {
            log.error(convertBlobToBytesException.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

When converting `Blob` into `byte[]` via the line:

```
reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length())
```

A `SQLExcpetion` is thrown. After turning on MSSQL JDBC trace logging, I found that the statement is being closed immediately after getting the `Blob` (i.e. right after executing this: `Blob reportData = carRepository.getReportData("sedan,truck", date);`). Here's the log:

> 2023-09-29T17:33:05.762-05:00 DEBUG 29104 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
> c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : ***
> SQLException:SQLServerCallableStatement:119
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement is
> closed. The statement is closed.
>
> 2023-09-29T17:33:05.771-05:00 ERROR 29104 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
> com.example.service.CarService      : got Blob

Then the log from `TDS.Channel` reports closing input stream, closing output stream and then closing TCP socket. Since the call to `reportData.getBytes` tries to read the bytes from this closed stream, it errors as follows:

> 2023-09-29T17:33:05.773-05:00 ERROR 29104 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
> com.example.service.CarService      :
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TDS protocol
> stream is not valid.

**Question**

How can I get the bytes from the Blob using Spring Data JPA?

**What I've tried**

I tried wrapping the `getValuations` method in a transaction but this causes the application to hang when reading packets from stored procedure call.

I can get the bytes without using Spring Data JPA as follows:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CarService {
  
    private final CarRepository carRepository;
    private final EntityManager em;

    public Set<CarDto> getValuations(LocalDate date) {
        
        StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("pValuation");
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("carTypes", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tradeDate", LocalDate.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportData", Blob.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        q.setParameter("carTypes", "sedan,truck");
        q.setParameter("tradeDate", date);
        q.execute();
        
        Blob reportData = (Blob) q.getOutputParameterValue("reportData");
        
        log.debug("got Blob");
        try {
            byte[] b= reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length());
            log.debug("got bytes");
            return carRepository.getCarValuations(b);
        } 
        catch (SQLException convertBlobToBytesException) {
                log.error(convertBlobToBytesException.toString());
        }
    }
```

This code works but I would like to know how to do this using Spring Data JPA.